# get with id, return another variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to create a get-method, which will get a barcode but return `qty != 0`.

In this code below I managed to get a barcode return `qty` or get barcode and return `qty == 0`. But when I am trying to get `qty != 0` I am getting this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.javahelps.restservice.controller.UserController.findd(UserController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

My code

```
@GetMapping(path = "/barcode/{barcode}")
public List<User> findd(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode,Integer qty) {
    return repository.findByQty(qty != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer qty` is defined as an object. If your Request does not contain a value for `qty`, the value of this variable is `null` and unboxing `null` to an `int` value for your check `qty != null` results in a `NullPointerException`, because there is no value for the variable you could unbox.

you must also add a mapping annotation to your variable e.g. `@RequestParam`.

To fix this, you could add a null-check:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/barcode/{barcode}")
public List<User> findd(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode, @RequestParam Integer qty) {
    if (qty == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return repository.findByQty(qty != 0);
}
```

Or your could make your variable of the primitive `int` type not allowing `null` values and defaulting to `0` in that case:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/barcode/{barcode}")
public List<User> findd(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode, @RequestParam int qty) {
    return repository.findByQty(qty != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer qty` will alway be `null`, because you do not set mapping for this value.

It could be marked as `@RequestParam`

```
@GetMapping(path = "/barcode/{barcode}")
public List<User> findd(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode,
                        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer qty) {
    return repository.findByQty(qty != 0);
}
```

In this snippet:

- `/barcode/{barcode}?qty=666` - `qty = 666`
- `/barcode/{barcode}` - `qty = 0` (defaualt value) or `null` if you define it as `@RequestParam Integer qty`

***P.S.** Do not forget that `Integer` is an `Object` and it can be `null`. In case you set `defaultValue` this will always be set an you can set `int` instead.*

Comment: i am getting thi error  https://imgur.com/a/3tkIZDT
Whenever i add != it shows me this, but =0 works perfectly